# Remove extra characters after file extension? (Rename)

Tags: batch, rename, characters

I'm using Windows XP software that creates .TIF files and adds a string of characters at the end of the file extension, i.e. "IMG1478.TIF_078210_418590".

Is there a script or other method that will remove the characters after the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Windows you're using. 
On Windows 7,

```
ren  *.TIF*  *.TIF
```

seems to work.